# Javascript file(s) not loading in view.jsp

Tags: javascript, html

In a web page I am developing, I am trying to include two javascript files. the code looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/configaudit-portlet/css/dynamicJSTable/gridtable.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/viper-theme/css/universal_buttons.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/configaudit-portlet/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/configaudit-portlet/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable_nextPrevious.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript>
           function blah(){
            .
            .
            .
```

The files are suppose to add additional formatting to tables that are loaded onto the page. I have used these files in the past on different pages with no problem at. I can load the jsp that creates the table with the files included with no problems. Nothing in the file has change only the file/path names which I have checked over and over and nothing seems to be wrong.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the full URL of the JSP file in browser address bar? What is the full URL of the JS file in browser address bar? Once you know both, extracting the (relative) URL for in `<script src>` is easy. If you already can't get the JS file by entering its full URL in browser address bar, then it's simply wrong or not there where you think it is.

Comment: Can you load the JS files by typing their url directly in the browser: http://mydomain.com/configaudit-portlet/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Are your files located at the root of your domain? The way you have it right now, the files will be searched for at the root. If you remove the leading `'/'`'s in your `src` definitions, they will be relative urls and files will be searched for in the same directory as your .html file.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is there is definately something wrong with your path to the js files.
What do you mean when you say that you checked over the paths?
Figure out your correct path of the js files, as you are saying that you changed the file/path names.

Answer (score 0):

End quote is missing in the inline block: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Have you tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable_nextPrevious.js"></script>
```

Or maybe, on the top of the page

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/dynamicJSTable/configaudit_gridtable_nextPrevious.js"/>"></script>
```